Need to have excel average every nth row only with data in it

I have a weekly scorecard that our leadership is going to fill out. Its all on one tab and has 500+ rows of the same scorecard that runs with the same statistics. I took a screen grab of one section. I am needing a scorecard at the very top that averages all the numbers. For example: the top scorecard will have the averages of all departments like HVAC Sales Revenue
The data is all exactly 65 rows apart and in column H.
We are going to continue adding weeks throughout the year so I need a formula that finds the data and only averages the data when there is data filled out.

Do you mean to take the by description in the column left from it? If so AVERAGEIF(S)

Correct data organization is the first action you need to start from.
A solution for you is to transpose the table:

Then you'll be able to summarize data as easily as never before:
[B2]=AVERAGE(B3:B54)

You can search SO to find a solution to pivot your existing data.
The pivot table is another right way

No comments.
An alternative way

[C13]=AVERAGEIF(B2:B10,B13:B15,C2:C10)


How is it going?

=GROUPBY(B2:B19,C2:C19,AVERAGE,,0,,(LEFT(B2:B19,5)<>"total")*(C2:C19<>""))

This way it doesn't matter if at one time a category gets added.

Another alternative workaround using AVERAGEIFS() :


=LET(
     a, B2:B19,
     b, C2:C19,
     c, AVERAGEIFS(b,b,"<>",a,a,a,"<>Total*"),
     UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(a,c),ISNUMBER(c))))


